# Org.apache.haoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.MetaException

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am getting a error like this,

```
Org.apache.haoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.MetaException
(message: for direct Metastore Db connections, we dont support retries at client level)
```

when i try to create a **table** in **hive**? Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Be Clear..and specific, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Post your hive configurations.